# Regex to get next line of match returns empty

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, scrapy, extract

According to this Regex [code](https://regex101.com/r/7G8jTK/1) for getting the next line of a match, the commented line of my code should work after i added " +([^\r\n]+) " to it. But for some reason it isn't working ...
I'm new to regex, so any tip is very welcome.

```
import scrapy
import json
class MlSpider(scrapy.Spider):
url1='https://produto.mercadolivre.com.br/MLB-1304118411-sandalia-feminina-anabela-confortavel-pingente-mac-cod-133-_JM?attributes=COLOR_SECONDARY_COLOR%3AUHJldGE%3D%2CSIZE%3AMzU%3D&quantity=1'
url2='https://www.mercadolivre.com.br/chinelo-kenner-rakka-pretolaranja-36-br-para-adulto-homem/p/MLB19132834?product_trigger_id=MLB19130858&attributes=COLOR%3APreto%2FAzul%2CSIZE%3A36+BR&pdp_filters=category%3AMLB273770%7Cshipping_cost%3Afree&applied_product_filters=MLB19132871&quantity=1'   
   name = 'detalhador'
   start_urls=[url2] 

   def parse(self, response,**kwargs):
           d = response.xpath("//script[contains(., 'window.__PRELOADED_STATE__')]/text()").re_first(r'(?s)window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = (.+?\});') # This only gets url1, because the following text of the string is in the same line as the string

           if not d : # so this was made to get url2 as well
                d = response.xpath("//script[contains(., 'window.__PRELOADED_STATE__')]/text()").re_first(r'(?s)window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = +([^\r\n]+)') #This should get the line bellow the matching string, but i dosent
```

Comment: `.xpath('//script[contains(., "window.PRELOADED_STATE")]/text()')` and `.xpath('//script[contains(., "window.__PRELOADED_STATE__")]/text()')` seem to return an  empty list.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew , Really ? But the first variable 'd', returns a big string.

Comment: Then add this relevant string part with expected match to the question. When I tested, I did not get it.

Comment: You're right. Hold on

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, done, i fixed the question. Now the url1 should return a big string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your regex expression.  You are not escaping certain symbols that regex uses internally as parsing tools and directions.  Also you are using the literal ' ' space character where there is actually a newline characte immidiately after the `=` sign.  Using `\s` is usually better because it means any whitespace character.

Try using this instead. I already tested and got the results you desire.

```
d = response.xpath("//script[contains(., 'window.__PRELOADED_STATE__')]/text()"
                   ).re_first(r'window\.__PRELOADED_STATE__\s?\=\s*?(\{.*?\});')
```

The `.{}=` characters are all used as parsing instructions by regex, so they need to be escaped with a `\` when you want to use the literal character in your expression.

I also removed the `(?s)` from the beginning of your expression, I'm not entirely sure why that was there.